# MySQL select products by filter

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select IDs of products which have specific value_id.

Table `products`:

```
| product_id | product_name | category_id | active |
| 125        | notebook1    | 3           | 1      |
| 236        | notebook2    | 3           | 1      |
```

Table `filters`:

```
| product_id | value_id | value_name |
| 125        | 35       | 15" display|
| 125        | 36       | 8GB RAM    |
| 236        | 35       | 15" display|
```

This select works ok, if I want to select products IDs by one value_id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id FROM products p
LEFT JOIN filters f ON (p.product_id=f.product_id)
WHERE p.active=1 AND p.category_id=3 AND f.value_id=36;
```

But when I check more filters on web, I need to select by more values, problem is that when I use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id FROM products p
LEFT JOIN filters f ON (p.product_id=f.product_id)
WHERE p.active=1 AND p.category_id=3 AND f.value_id IN(35,36);
```

It gives me products which have 15" display **OR** 8GB RAM, I need products which have 15" display **AND** 8GB RAM. Thanks.

Comment: why using "DISTINCT" ?

Comment: because of join... and in filters table there are more rows with the same product_id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume since you mentioned web that you are using a program language to generate the queries.  I am also going to assume that you do not have control over how the data is structured in the tables so we have to have an option that will work given the table structure provided.

The below option works but will get sloppy if you are dealing with large numbers of options being passed in.

### Option Using Subsequent Joins for Each Option

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT p.product_id 
FROM 
    products p
JOIN filters f1 
    ON p.product_id=f1.product_id
    and f1.value_id = 35
JOIN filters f2 
    ON p.product_id=f2.product_id
    and f2.value_id = 36
WHERE 
    p.active=1 
    AND p.category_id=3
;
```

If you get your filter value ids in a comma delimited list and want to use it in that fashion (hints your IN statement) you can take this approach.  I am making the assumption that you know the total number of filter values passed in.  In your example you had 2 so the query would like this.

### Group Count Equal to Filters Provided w/ IN Statement

```
SELECT 
    p.product_id
FROM 
    products p
JOIN filters f 
    ON p.product_id=f.product_id
    AND p.active=1 
    AND p.category_id=3 
    AND f.value_id IN(35,36)
GROUP BY
    p.product_id
HAVING
    COUNT(p.product_id) = 2
```

Also putting as much in your join condition rather than the where clause will help speed up the query since the from clause is evaluated before the where clause.

Comment: first query 0.0055s, second query 3.3348s, I will go for first solution, thanks.

Comment: I don't really get why you say this will be faster than a `where` clause. It is known to be exactly the same as the filtering happens at the same time. Can you provide a link to the official documentation supporting that comment? As a side note, the FROM executes before the WHERE clause but the JOIN is not in a FROM clause, am I right?

Comment: first select with joins after applying 12 filters and more other arguments after where lasts 0.0019s, great :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT product_id FROM filters
WHERE value_id IN (35, 36)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value_id) = 2
```

This will output `125`.

Note that if a given `product_id` can not have the same `value_id` more than once then you can remove the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/545dd7/1).

The complete query based on your last one is:

```
SELECT f.product_id FROM filters f
JOIN products p ON f.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE f.value_id IN (35, 36) AND p.active = 1 AND p.category_id = 3
GROUP BY f.product_id
HAVING COUNT(f.value_id) = 2
```

Comment: good idea, I can count number of filtered values, so number after having count will be calculated by php

Comment: @MichalTinka If one product has two same options is this working? i.e. 1 PC has 2 displays.

Comment: after adding indexes the second query lasts 8.8491s, the nested select rotates 1108 times and searches between 103 rows

Comment: @JungsuHeo there is no product (and cannot be) with two the same values.

Comment: @MichalTinka aha! Then sub-query is not needed. Just add group by product_id having count = 2. If it is not running. I will modify after having runch.

Comment: with join it lasts "only" 3,9259s

Answer (score 0):

If you need an output of 15" display AND 8GB RAM.

```
    SELECT product_id FROM products
WHERE product_id IN(SELECT DISTINCT product_id from filters WHERE value_id IN(35,35) GROUP BY value_name)
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8599d/11)

Comment: sorry, I need it universal for more products, not only with ID 125

Comment: @MichalTinka oh i see . you want to filter with multiple `value_id` am i right?

Comment: i think a tweaks on that is grouping it by value_name, so that you will only get one product_di with unique value_name